# How to get output in one line

Tags: python

I do reverse string and input is The quick brow fox

```
def reverse_word(word):
    for i in word:
      re = (i[::-1])
      print('Reversed words ==> '+ re )

def main():
    word = input('Enter a line : ').split()
    reverse_word(word)
main()
```

but my result is

```
Reversed words ==> ehT
Reversed words ==> kciuq
Reversed words ==> worb
Reversed words ==> xof
```

I want result like:

```
Reversed words ==> ehT kciuq worb xof
```

Comment: You can have a global variable `out = ""` and then add the strings to this in the for loop `out = out + " " + re` and `print` at the end.

Comment: you print "Reversed words" in every iteration of your for-loop but you need only one print. You can start with fixing that issue.

Answer (score 1):

you can use end in print method

```
def reverse_word(word):
    print('Reversed words ==> ', end='')
    for i in word:
      re = (i[::-1])
      print(re, end=' ' )

def main():
    word = input('Enter a line : ').split()
    reverse_word(word)
main()
```

Answer (score 0):

When you say `word` it looks like this is really a collection of words, so `words` is probably a better name, and each of those should probably be `word` rather than `i`.

```
def reverse_words(words):
    for word in words:
      re = (word[::-1])
      print('Reversed words ==> '+ re )

def main():
    words = input('Enter a line : ').split()
    reverse_words(words)

main()
```

Now, we can use a generator expression to generate the reversed word for each word.

```
(word[::-1] for word in words)
```

And let's join those with a space.

```
' '.join(word[::-1] for word in words)
```

And putting it into a function, using an f-string to print it:

```
def reverse_words(words):
    print(f"Reversed words ==> {' '.join(word[::-1] for word in words)}")
```

Alternatively, we can use `reversed`.

```
def reverse_words(words):
    print(f"Reversed words ==> {' '.join(''.join(reversed(word)) for word in words)}")
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to get a single line output , you can have a global string 
 `out = ""`
 To which you will concatenate your resulting words.

```
out += " " + re
```

Inside the `for loop`
And this can be printed right after the end of the loop.

```
out = ""
def reverse_word(word):
    for i in word:
      re = (i[::-1])
      out += " " + re
    print("Reversed Words ==> " + out)

def main():
    word = input('Enter a line : ').split()
    reverse_word(word)
main()
```

Comment: your code is producing error, have you even checked it?

Comment: add `global out` above the line where you referenced out

Answer (score 0):

Can try this one :

```
def reverse_word(word):
    print("Reversed words ==>", end="")
    for i in word:
        re = (i[::-1])
        print(" " + re, end="")


def main():
    word = input('Enter a line : ').split()
    reverse_word(word)


main()
```

Comment: This answer could use some explanation, rather than just code.

Answer (score 0):

```
def reverse_word(word):
    res = ""
    for i in word:
      re = (i[::-1])
      res += " "+re
    return 'Reversed words ==>'+ res

word = input('Enter a line : ').split()
print(reverse_word(word))
```

Believe this would have desired effect.

Not really a question asked so no need to explain it further. Keep it simple!